# How to solve many if else statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have no idea about how to tackle many `if/else` statements in python.

Here is my dictionary object which is shown below. There are nearly 30 values containing characters and strings in the `dict` object.

```
{
     'a': 0, 
     'b': 1,
     'c': 2,
     'd': 3,
     'e': 4,
     'f': 5,
     'g': 6,
     'h': 7,
     ...
     'aba': 7,
     ...
}
```

When I input the key value of the dictionary, it returns its value.

```
key= input('Enter object key : ')
answer= getValue(key)
```

How can I define a `getValue()` method?

Comment: can you please explain how getValue() methods works for you? and how that method can achieve the desired output for you

Comment: your input and desired output?

Comment: Is the only purpose of the dictionary to get the value of a character so that a = 0, b =1, c = 2... and so on up to z = 25? If so, then you don't need a dictionary but just `answer = ord(key)-ord('a')`

Comment: @Umair Mubeen I want to get any value with respect to its search key. However, the list is not short. I want to get values without using writing too many conditions.

Comment: @Guy Incognito I want to use a dictionary. The Dictionary contains not only characters but also string like "aba". How can I do that?

Comment: Uh... `dict[key]`?

Comment: @Guy Incognito How can I get values from search criteria? How can I define the function?

Comment: what output do you want for key=a?

Comment: `def getValue(key): return dict[key]`

Comment: @warped its value is 0. For example , When I enter "aba", it returns 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want the value of your dictionary.
If that's the case, try:

```
your_dict = {
     'a': 0, 
     'b': 1,
     'c': 2,
     'd': 3,
     'e': 4,
     'f': 5,
     'g': 6,
     'h': 7,
     ...
}

key= input('Enter object key : ')
answer = your_dict[key]
```

I would also recommend to use a input filter, to check if the input is a valid key of your dict or otherwise, you will receive an error.

```
def getInput():
    key= input('Enter object key : ')
    if key in your_dict:
        return key
    else:
        print("invalid input, try again")
        getInput()
```

so instead of `key= input('Enter object key : ')` you'd write `key = getInput()`